# Hi iam working on exercises from phyton textbook and i have the following error in the code

Tags: jupyter-notebook

this is from introduction to machine learning text

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(15, 10))
for ax, C in zip(axes, [-1, 0, 3]):
for a, gamma in zip(ax, range(-1, 2)):
```

I get a error as below:

```
for a, gamma in zip(ax, range(-1, 2)):

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Sounds like it expects some indentation. I see none. Read https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `for` loop is supposed to be *inside* the first one(nested). And python does not **forgive** whitespace errors. Basically *indent* the second loop like so:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(15, 10))

for ax, C in zip(axes, [-1, 0, 3]):
    for a, gamma in zip(ax, range(-1, 2)): # < error right here
```

Comment: i still get the same can you help me writing the correct syntax

Comment: Yould you supply your full code on repl.it? We can then see what the issue is

Comment: @dnivara Please provide full code. Also I hope there is some logic under the for loop. As otherwise there is no use i nmaking one anyway...

Comment: from sklearn.svm import SVC
X, y = mglearn.tools.make_handcrafted_dataset()
svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=10, gamma=0.1).fit(X, y)
mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(svm, X, eps=.5)
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
# plot support vectors
sv = svm.support_vectors_
# class labels of support vectors are given by the sign of the dual coefficients
sv_labels = svm.dual_coef_.ravel() > 0
mglearn.discrete_scatter(sv[:, 0], sv[:, 1], sv_labels, s=15, markeredgewidth=3)
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")

Comment: plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(15, 10))
for ax, C in zip(axes, [-1, 0, 3]):
    for a, gamma in zip(ax, range(-1, 2)):